# No message found under code 'avatar.path' for locale 'ru_RU'. error in spring

Tags: spring

my code:

```
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(ApplicationContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    }
     ...     
     Locale bundle = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").setRegion("RU").build(); 
     String av = context.getMessage("avatar.path", null, bundle);
```

error:

> No message found under code 'avatar.path' for locale 'ru_RU'.

beans.xml

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="messages"> </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
```

messsages_ru_RU.properties in folder src/main/resources/

```
avatar.path = resources/image/avatar.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the file suppose to be in WEB-INF?

You can specify any values you like, but I think it has to be relative to WEB-INF:
The sampel below is working for me.

```
 <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messagesT" />
</bean>
```

Comment: file in myapp/src/main/resources/messsages_ru_RU.properties

Comment: @user1480528 it is suppose to be in : myapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/messages_ru.properties

Comment: my code work if write from jsp page
<fmt:message key="avatar.path"></fmt:message>
and don't work in directory WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

You may try with file name `messages_ru_RU.properties`